# How can I have 2 different code implementations for GWT whether you're on the client or on the server side

Tags: java, gwt

I have a logging library (among other) which is pretty powerful using network, etc. it is used all around the code we have. Some of the code we have is simple and should be used on the client side of GWT, but as it uses calls to this library, it fails compilation.

I was thinking I could write a specific library that would have the same calls / API but point to different implementation.

I naively looked at:

```
<replace-with class="someClass">
    <when-type-is class="javax.validation.ValidatorFactory" />
</replace-with>
```

but I wanted some feedback first.

Comment: Have you ever used Guice? GIN is a nice solution to integrate several implementation of your interface in GWT client code.

Comment: I have not... I must admit I was expecting an easy solution and not discover another tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"super source" FTW!

See *“Overriding one package implementation with another”* at http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html